# How to change the vertical datum of a geotiff DEM

Tags: gdal, elevation, datum, vertical

I am trying to do some change detection between SFM derived DEM products, but the DEM i would like to use as my base elevation (and one other) is in NAD83, the remainder are WGS84.  I would like to reproject the raster values (elevations) to WGS84 datum. Arcmap 10.4 cannot do vertical datum shifts, and VDatum does not seem to be changing the values within the raster when asked to do a datum shift, because it does not 'know' that the values are elevation.  Can I use GDAL or rasterio to tackle this problem?  I am new to geospatial analysis in python, but I am familiar with the language .

Comment: Do you mean that the one is on NAVD88 rather than NAD83 and/or the WGS84 z values are geoidal versus ellipsoidal? If both are using ellipsoidal heights which is implied by NAD83 / WGS84, there won't be much change in height. If one or the other is on a geoid / gravity-related surface, then I'd expect to see a change.